# Math.random() in an array?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>
<body>

  <button onclick="myFunction()">Summon</button>
  <p id="demo"></p>

  <script>
    var luck = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'],
        lucknumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * luck.length));
    if (lucknumber < 4) { 
      <p>SR</p>
    }
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my script so far, but when I click `Summon`, nothing shows up - my intention was for it to randomise and come out with a number from `luck`, and make the number come out with an image. (assigned) sorry for the newbie question.

Idk if it's an obvious problem, but I can't seem to find it, I just started learning .js :)

Comment: You can't embed markup in javascript like that.

Comment: As for "nothing shows up" - check your browser console for errors, you'll see why.

Comment: Where is `myFunction` function declared?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be looking for this.

```js
function myFunction()
{
    var luck= ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'],
    lucknumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * luck.length));
    if (lucknumber < 4){
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "SR";
    }
    else
    {
        alert("not lucky");
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Summon</button>
<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```